# Protobuf.Any - Unmarshal from a json.RawMessage

Tags: go, protobuf-go

I have data from the DB that is in `json.RawMessage` format. The specific column is jsonb.

I can't really find a way to unmarshal the data to a property that on proto is defined as protobuf.Any like so.

```protobuf
repeated google.protobuf.Any list = 1;
```

When I try to unmarshal the data from the db using `json.Unmarshal()` then `list` is empty. The documentation mention something like this:

```golang
foo := &pb.Foo{...}
 any, err := anypb.New(foo)
 if err != nil {
   ...
 }
 ...
 foo := &pb.Foo{}
 if err := any.UnmarshalTo(foo); err != nil {
   ...
 }
```

But in this example `foo` is of type `proto.Message` which I can't convert since I have `json.RawMessage`.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should understand what is stored in the DB column. `json.RawMessage` is simply defined as `type RawMessage []byte` (see [the doc](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#RawMessage)). And it does not carry enough information to answer your question.

I will provide a demo to show how `google.protobuf.Any` works, which should help you understand your question better.

**Notes**:

1. [Any](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any) is for embedding other types in a message. So I define two other messages (`Foo` and `Bar`) in the demo.

   > The `Any` message type lets you use messages as embedded types without having their .proto definition. An Any contains an arbitrary serialized message as bytes, along with a URL that acts as a globally unique identifier for and resolves to that message's type.
2. Actually, your question depends on what is stored in the DB. See the comments in `main.go`.

---

Folder structure of the demo:

```
├── go.mod
├── main.go
└── pb
    ├── demo.pb.go
    └── demo.proto
```

`go.mod`:

```
module github.com/ZekeLu/demo

go 1.19

require (
    github.com/golang/protobuf v1.5.2
    google.golang.org/protobuf v1.28.1
)
```

`pb/demo.proto`:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package pb;

import "google/protobuf/any.proto";

option go_package = "github.com/ZekeLu/demo/pb";

message MyMessage {
  repeated google.protobuf.Any list = 1;
}

message Foo {
  int32 v = 1;
}

message Bar {
  string v = 1;
}
```

`main.go`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/anypb"

    "github.com/ZekeLu/demo/pb"
)

func main() {
    // If the db stores an instance of pb.Foo, then unmarshal it first.
    buf := json.RawMessage([]byte(`{"v":10}`))
    var foo pb.Foo
    err := json.Unmarshal(buf, &foo)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // And then marshal it into a new Any instance, which can be used to
    // create a slice that can be assigned to pb.MyMessage.List.
    a1, err := anypb.New(&foo)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    bar := &pb.Bar{V: "10"}
    a2, err := anypb.New(bar)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Initialize the List field.
    m := pb.MyMessage{List: []*anypb.Any{a1, a2}}

    buf, err = json.Marshal(&m)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", buf)
    // Output: {"list":[{"type_url":"type.googleapis.com/pb.Foo","value":"CAo="},{"type_url":"type.googleapis.com/pb.Bar","value":"CgIxMA=="}]}

    // If the db stores the output above, it can be unmarshal directly
    var m2 pb.MyMessage
    err = json.Unmarshal(buf, &m2)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", m2.List)
    // Output: [[type.googleapis.com/pb.Foo]:{v:10} [type.googleapis.com/pb.Bar]:{v:"10"}]
}
```

Steps to run the demo:

```
$ protoc --proto_path=pb --go_out=pb --go_opt=paths=source_relative demo.proto
$ go mod tidy
$ go run main.go
```

Comment: Thanks @Zeke Lu for the explanation! Really appreciate it!